# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS wont boot after installation (along side windows 11) on Asus tuf F15 RTX 3070

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, kernel, nouveau

Following are the errors I am getting and unable to resolve these:

```
snd_hda_intel no codecs found!

usci_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110) 

nouveau: failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 error

Bluetooth: hcio: Reading Intel version information failed (-22)
[6.819288] Bluetooth: hcio: Intel Read version failed (-22)
[7.416262] Bluetooth: hcio: Reading Intel version information failed (-22)
[7.416358] Bluetooth: hcio: Intel Read version failed (-22)
[7.984328] usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[8.220598] usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error
-71
[8.584241] usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error
-71
[8.820267] usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error
-71
[9.996190] usb 3-10: device not accepting address 13, error
-71
[10.540208] usb 3-10: device not accepting address 14, error
-71
[10.540609] usb usb3-port10: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Please help

Comment: You need to understand this https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot because you're dual-booting with Windows 11 and Windows 11 requires Secure Boot enabled. Otherwise it would be as simple as disabling it.

Comment: I suspect it is an Nvidia driver problem. Install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)